# Wrong type hints when the attribute name is the same as the class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

```
from typing import get_type_hints, Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Wife:
    name: str = ''


@dataclass
class Husband:
    name: str = ''
    wife: Optional[Wife] = None


@dataclass
class HusbandNew:
    name: str = ''
    Wife: Optional[Wife] = None


get_type_hints(Husband)
>>> {'name': str, 'wife': typing.Union[__main__.Wife, NoneType]}
get_type_hints(HusbandNew)
>>> {'name': str, 'Wife': NoneType}
```

I'm using `Python 3.7.4`. The only difference between `HusbandNew` and `Husband` is the `wife`/`Wife` attribute (`Wife` is also the class name). Why do they produce different type hints?

In python, we usually use PascalCase for class names and snake_case for attribute names. However, I often deal with external APIs which return JSON. I copy that JSON to https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate `dataclasses` with type annotations. It produces class names same as attribute names.